# How to Serialize JSON that changes to a C# Class with RestSharp?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, restsharp

I've got this JSON here:

```
{
    "id": "-KDYmr0aI0UmjKRyd465",
    "name": "No Name",
    "presentation": {
      "fields": [
        {
          "defaultValue": "Erste Node",
          "id": "test",
          "title": "test",
          "type": "text"
        },
        {
          "defaultValue": "Zweite node",
          "id": "test2",
          "title": "test2",
          "type": "text"
        }
      ]
    },
    "thumbnail": "/images/defaultimage.png",
    "updated": "2016-03-23T14:05:32+00:00",
    "userData": {
      "test": "Erste Node",
      "test2": "Zweite node"
    }
  }
```

The userData changes depending on if the user added some data. So lets say the user added some data like `{"test3":"More testdata"}` the userdata json would look like this:

```
 "userData": {
      "test": "Erste Node",
      "test2": "Zweite node",
      "test3": "More testdata"
    }
```

Also the fields would be updating accordingly but i know how i would map those fields to a C# Class.
My question is how i would be able to serialize this userData as a C# Class - but also with the use of the RestSharp Client from here: http://restsharp.org/

That's pretty much how my classes would look like. But i don't know how to map the userData...

```
public class Field
{
    public string defaultValue { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Presentation
{
    public List<Field> fields { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Presentation presentation { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string updated { get; set; }
    public UserData userData { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize the json to a c# class using [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) which I am sure you are aware of (I think RestSharp uses this library). When you get your json back from the service use DeserializeObject and define a class to map to:

```
var json = "{ \"id\": \"-KDYmr0aI0UmjKRyd465\", \"name\": \"No Name\", \"presentation\": { \"fields\": [ { \"defaultValue\": \"Erste Node\", \"id\": \"test\", \"title\": \"test\", \"type\": \"text\" }, { \"defaultValue\": \"Zweite node\", \"id\": \"test2\", \"title\": \"test2\", \"type\": \"text\" } ] }, \"thumbnail\": \"/images/defaultimage.png\", \"updated\": \"2016-03-23T14:05:32+00:00\", \"userData\": { \"test\": \"Erste Node\", \"test2\": \"Zweite node\" } }";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Now to deal with the userData node that can change to different lengths I would change my class to a 'dynamic' type which can handle this data. So my class would become:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Presentation presentation { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string updated { get; set; }
    public dynamic userData { get; set; }
}
```

To iterate your dynamic userData property:

```
foreach(var data in result.userData)
{
    var name = data.Name;
    var value = data.Value;
}
```

Comment: I've never used dynamic classes like this. Can i iterate through those or how would i use them in my case?

Answer (score 2):

One quick tip here is, for user data you should use Dictionary. This will give flexibility to add as many userData dynamically(key value pairs). Important thing is, This will serialize in to JSON like a normal class.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can use Dictionary for userData property

```
public class Field
{
    public string defaultValue { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Presentation
{
    public List<Field> fields { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Presentation presentation { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string updated { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> userData { get; set; }
}
```